# How to set up a scheduled cypress test on github action to run one spec file only?

Tags: cron, cypress, github-actions

I have set up a cron job for my cypress tests however I want to run it on a specific test alone.
This is my cron job:

```
name: Cypress Tests

on: [push]

jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # Install NPM dependencies, cache them correctly
      # and run all Cypress tests
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4.x.x # use the explicit version number
        with:
          build: npm run build
          start: npm start
```

I just want to run this one spec file:

[image]

Is there a way to run this spec file alone?

Comment: Does this [link](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#How-to-run-commands) help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out!

1. Add new command in script section of package.json. Use file or folder here.

```
  "scripts": {
    "cypress:spec-run": "cypress run --browser chrome --spec test.spec.js"
  },
```

2. Run the commond in respective crone job
   `npm run cypress:spec-run`